# Asp.net Core Web API - Downloading multiple images from blob storage to zip file (via Axios get)

Tags: c#, vue.js, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, axios

I am trying to download a zip file containing a number of files (of various types) - while i do indeed get a zip file downloading, it unfortunately throws the following error when i attempt to open it:

[zip file error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQL1A.png)

The images are stored using azure blob storage.

Please help if you have any ideas.

I have a button in my Vue.js front end that calls the following:

```
    GetAllAssetResources ({commit},id)
    {
        console.log("Getting Asset Resources:" + id);
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            axios.get(CONFIG.platformEndPoints+  '/asset/downloadResources/' + id)
            .then( (response) => {
                const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
                const link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = url;
                link.setAttribute('download', 'resources.zip');
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
            })
        })
    }
```

This calls my controller method (using C#):

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadResources(string guid)
    {
        return File(await _ResourceService.DownloadAllAssetResources(guid), MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "resources");
    }
```

This calls my service:

```
    public async Task<byte[]> DownloadAllAssetResources(string guid)
    {
        var assetDetails = await _AssetDetails.FindAsync(guid);
        var resources = assetDetails.res.ToList();
        byte[] archiveFile;

        await using (var archiveStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var archive = new ZipArchive(archiveStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
            {
                foreach (var file in resources)
                {
                    var fileName = guid+ "_" + file.name;
                    var zipArchiveEntry = archive.CreateEntry(fileName, CompressionLevel.Fastest);
                    var bytes = await _Storage.GetBytes("resources", fileName);

                    await using (var zipStream = zipArchiveEntry.Open())
                    {
                        zipStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    }
                }
            }

            archiveFile = archiveStream.ToArray();
        }

        return archiveFile;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It was just a case of updating my axios call to include the response type:

```
        GetAllAssetResources ({commit},assetDetailid)
    {
        console.log("Getting Asset Resources:" + id);
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            axios({
                url: CONFIG.platformEndPoints+  '/asset/downloadResources/' + id,
                method: 'GET',
                responseType: 'blob'})
            .then( (response) => {
                const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
                const link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = url;
                link.setAttribute('download', 'resources.zip');
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
            })
        })
    },
```